# how to get name from array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, element

I have an array of [objects](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Object) in array notation. This array is going to be different every time.

I wish to be able to get the name of the elements in this array. The trouble I am having is that [object] is returned instead of returning assetA, for example. I know this is because assetA is an object itself.

An example of the code I have been using to test this is..

```
//the assetArray will have varying number of elements in the future
var assetArray=[assetX,assetY,assetZ, assetB, assetA];
var testtest=(new String(assetArray));
alert(testtest);
$.each(assetArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    var test123=(new String(assetArray[intIndex]));
    alert(test123);
});
```

and the list of test assets are..

```
var assetX = {
    assetNumber: "TESTX",
    assetDescription: "FLUX CAPACITOR",
    assetManufacturer: "Honeywell",
    assetCustomer: "MCFLY",
    assetDate: "03/04/1956"
};
var assetY = {
    assetNumber: "C123Y",
    assetDescription: "HOVERBOARD",
    assetManufacturer: "GE",
    assetCustomer: "MCFLY",
    assetDate: "12/03/1945"
};
var assetZ = {
    assetNumber: "9000Z",
    assetDescription: "ROCKETFOOTBALL",
    assetManufacturer: "Fluke",
    assetCustomer: "MCFLY JR.",
    assetDate: "01/05/3030"
};
var assetA = {
    assetNumber: "C34JJXA",
    assetDescription: "TEST DESCRIPTION",
    assetManufacturer: "Elgar",
    assetCustomer: "CUSTOMER1",
    assetDate: "05/09/1923"
};
var assetB = {
    assetNumber: "C892ALB",
    assetDescription: "DMM",
    assetManufacturer: "Agilent",
    assetCustomer: "CUSTOMER2",
    assetDate: "02/12/1986"
};
```

Does anyone have experience with this kind of issue using jQuery?

Comment: Why not use a JSON array, which can have both keys (aka "names") and values?

Comment: What are you expecting to get back?  The variable name?

Comment: @kingjiv I want to get back "assetA" or "assetB".

Comment: `assetA` or `assetB` are variable names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your asset objects in an object as properties (i.e. use an associative array instead of an ordinal array):

```
var assets = {
    assetX: {
        assetNumber: "TESTX",
        assetDescription: "FLUX CAPACITOR",
        assetManufacturer: "Honeywell",
        assetCustomer: "MCFLY",
        assetDate: "03/04/1956"
    },
    assetY: {
        assetNumber: "C123Y",
        assetDescription: "HOVERBOARD",
        assetManufacturer: "GE",
        assetCustomer: "MCFLY",
        assetDate: "12/03/1945"
    },
    ...
};

$.each(assets, function (name, asset) {
    // name is the name (e.g. "assetX")
    // asset is the object instance
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as the name of an object. There are objects, full stop. There are zero or more variables which refer to a given object, full stop. You can't go from an object to the variables that reference it, full stop, new paragraph.

If this "name" is an important property of the object itself, include it in the object (add a `name` field) or use an associative array (aka namespace, an object under the hood) with this "name" being the key and the asset objects being the values instead of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to display.

But you can just display the individual parts of the Object:

```
//the assetArray will have varying number of elements in the future
var assetArray=[assetX,assetY,assetZ, assetB, assetA];
var testtest=(new String(assetArray));
alert(testtest);
$.each(assetArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    var test123=objValue.assetNumber; //etc
    alert(test123);
});
```

Comment: I want to get back the names that are in the assetArray, i.e. "assetX".

Comment: @Turbo, you can't do that... you can add a name field to the object and then just display that `objValue.name`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a regular JavaScript object to match object names to values.

Comment: "JSON array" is not the best way to put it. You probably mean a regular JavaScript object.